# React Updating Same State with Different Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my App I have an `update` function.

```
update: function() {
    this.setState({
        red:this.refs.red1.refs.range.getDOMNode().value
        green:this.refs.green1.refs.range.getDOMNode().value,
        blue:this.refs.blue1.refs.range.getDOMNode().value
    })
},
```

I want to add a red2 ref and update the red state.  How do I do this?  Adding another `red:` would just overwrite the first one.

`Edit:`

I tried adding an `update2` function.  Which updates the state as expected.  I only have one issue with the code.  When I change `red2` to some number, `red1` doesn't change.  It's value should be the state.  I guess since I'm not calling `red1`'s `update` function its value doesn't get updated to match the current state.

```
update2: function() {
    this.setState({
        red: this.refs.red2.refs.range.getDOMNode().value,
        green: this.refs.green2.refs.range.getDOMNode().value,
        blue: this.refs.blue2.refs.range.getDOMNode().value,
    })
},
```

XML representation:

```
<ColorPicker ref="red1" min={0} max={255} step={1} val={this.state.red} update={this.update} />
<ColorPicker ref="red2" min={0} max={255} step={1} val={this.state.red} update={this.update2} type="number" />
```

How do I get `red1` and `red2` to update the state **and** have the state reflected as their value whenever one of the two components changes.

`Edit 2:`

Color picker component:

```
var ColorPicker = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        min: React.PropTypes.number,
        max: React.PropTypes.number,
        step: React.PropTypes.number,
        val: React.PropTypes.number,
        label: React.PropTypes.string,
        update: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        type: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['number', 'range']),
    },
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            min: null,
            max: null,
            val: 0,
            step: 1,
            label: '',
            type: 'range',
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    ref="range"
                    type={this.props.type}
                    min={this.props.min}
                    max={this.props.max}
                    step={this.props.step}
                    defaultValue={this.props.val}
                    onChange={this.props.update}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: so the value of red is based on a function of both red1 and red2 ?

Comment: @nilgun Yeah, I have a range slider and a number input.  I want both of those inputs to 1). reflect the value of the red state **and** 2). update red's state on change.  I updated the code with some more thoughts.

Comment: Can you post the code for ColorPicker component. It is like val prop does not set the value when it is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only setting the defaultValue so when second colorPicker changes the value of red, firstColorPicker is not updated:

Instead of using

```
defaultValue ={this.props.val}
```

use

```
value={this.props.val}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7ktbmwo/

Comment: How did you know this would fix the issue?  I don't understand why setting the value in the component would matter when its being updated in the App.  Can you shed some light for me?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: When you use defaultValue with the input control in the ColorPicker component you are creating an uncontrolled component. To update it via prop you need a controlled component. see this: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html